# What's the meaning of column Level in table AllDocs?

Tags: sql-server, sql

I know it's not the most orthodox way, but 
I am trying to count files in a huge list with a sql straight into the AllDocs table.

I see most files have one row only while 
 others have one row with column Level 1 and another row with column Level=255

I would like to know what is the meaning of the column **Level**
and if it is enough to restrict my query

```
From AllDocs Where level=1
```

so as to avoid duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indicates whether document is draft, published, or checked out.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh656481%28v=office.12%29.aspx